# Is it possible to get document of iframe with iframe_id?

Tags: dom, iframe

AFAIK,I can achieve this goal by window.frames['frame_name']

but if I only know frame_id,is it possible to get the content too?

You can try it out here:

http://maishudi.com/rte-light-read-only/index.html

btw,is it possible to get location attribute through iframe_id?

I tried long ago but failed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it. It works on (the latest) firefox, safari, camino and opera (mac).

You should still do some testing though (especially in IE)

```
var iframeObj = document.getElementById("theIframeId");
var documentObj = iframeObj.contentWindow || iframeObj.contentDocument;
var location = documentObj.location.href; // I think this only works if
                                          // the content of the iframe comes 
                                          // from the same domain.
```

Comment: I've tested it's not working.
You can test it here :
http://maishudi.com/rte-light-read-only/index.html


using :

var iframeObj = document.getElementById("id_description");
var documentObj = iframeObj.contentWindow || iframeObj.contentDocument;
alert(documentObj) ;

Comment: maybe IE?
It failed in firefox.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/oy48ul

this works because you are using iframe_name,not iframe_id..

Comment: no, there were both methods tested. I edited it now and left only the one with contentWindow/Document

Comment: oh,yes,it works!
btw,is it possible to get location attribute through iframe_id?
I tried long ago,but failed.

Comment: You can access the location object from documentObj.
documentObj.location.href will give you the address. I think that there are some security issues here, and it can't be accessed if the content from the iframe is from a different domain.